# How to exit from Chef HWRP resource if something looks not right?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm extending Chef resource. So created `libraries/my_custom_resource.rb` file. Where is `class MyCustomResource < Chef::Provider::Package::Yum` and ruby code... How should I exit from the resource `my_custom_resource.rb`when something going wrong or not satisfied to complete the resource action?

I want to exit only from `libraries/my_custom_resource.rb` so below code in recipe should be executed.

Comment: Don't get your point. Throwing an exception (`raise`)?

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to fail something. I want to just avoid doing something inside of `libraries/my_custom_resource.rb` and just report with `Chef::Log.info`. I'm thinking isn't `return` to skip the code?

Comment: This part of code is under `def` so I need to exit from definition or ideally from the class `class MyCustomResource`. Thanks

Comment: `return` is not enough ? Show your code if you want a real advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tensibai mentioned, `return` is what you want. An action method is at heart just some Ruby code. Normal programming practices apply.

Comment: `return` works well inside of libraries (HWRP resources). You can just simply add `return if something_not_satisfied` this will stop doing the action. Thanks!